# can not understand the result of np.where(array1==array2)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a code below:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[0., 4., 1.0],[2., 3., 2.0]])
argm=a.argmax(axis=0)
m=a[argm,np.arange(3)]
print (np.where(a == m))
```

I can not understand the result:

```
(array([0, 1, 1], dtype=int64), array([1, 0, 2], dtype=int64))
```

anyone can explain it?
thank you very much!!

Comment: for coordinate pairs: `print (*zip(*np.where(a == m)))`
`(0, 1) (1, 0) (1, 2)` broadcasting works with the axis array format `a[np.where(a == m)]`
`Out[89]: array([ 4.,  2.,  2.])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your a and m arrays look like this:

```
In [2]: a
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0.,  4.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  2.]])

In [5]: m
Out[5]: array([ 2.,  4.,  2.])
```

This is the result of `a == m`:

```
In [7]: a == m
Out[7]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

You can think of the result of `np.where(a==m)` as returning pairs of coordinates: the first `True` it located is in row 0 (as seen in the first returned array), column 1 (per the second one), as you can verify for yourself. The second one is in row 1, column 0. Likewise for the third one.

Is that clear enough?

You may also want to look at the docs for [numpy.nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero), which is what `numpy.where` collapses to when given a single argument.

Comment: what's `2` in the output `[1, 0, 2]` then?

Comment: That's column 2, the last one (in zero-based ordering)! Note that you've got a 2x3 matrix.

Comment: that is, search the 'True' element according to the row, one by one?

Comment: Pretty much! That's exactly what `numpy.nonzero` does.